# Embedding Google Maps minus fixed header and footer

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, height, embedding

I am trying to get google maps to fill out the whole content area minus a fixed header and fixed footer.

I have used the following CSS

```
.google-maps {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
.google-maps {position: relative; padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.google-maps iframe {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

and this script to calculate the padding-bottom, which would define the height:

```
<script>
var setHeight = function() {
    var topHeight = $('.regular-header').outerHeight();
    var bottomHeight = $('.sticky-footer').outerHeight();
    var contentHeight = $(window).height() - (topHeight + bottomHeight);
    $('.google-maps').css({'padding-bottom': contentHeight + 'px'});
}

$(window).load(function() {
    setHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
});
</script>
```

but I kind of think I am overcomplicating it and also can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution on [a codepen](https://codepen.io/lunev/pen/vYEEPjr/)!
I've changed $(window).load --> $(window).on('load')

```
    var resizeTimer;
    var setHeight = function() {
        var topHeight = $('.regular-header').outerHeight();
        var bottomHeight = $('.sticky-footer').outerHeight();
        var contentHeight = $(window).height() - (topHeight + bottomHeight);
        $('.google-maps').css({'padding-bottom': contentHeight + 'px'});
    }

    $(window).on('load', function() {
        setHeight();
    }).on('resize', function() {
      clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
      resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        setHeight();           
      }, 250);   
    });
```

Also, if you're used to something like jQuery UI resizeable, you get events you can bind to during the resizing, but also at the end of resizing. So, I've added a debounce function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Obviously it works, but somehow I must make a mistake, because the padding-bottom CSS won't show in developer tools. My script is in the source code, so it loads I guess.